# Raise JSON Schema Validation Error when key does not exist in API Gateway

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, model, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

Having some issues trying to get to AWS API Gateway to error.
Validation errors raise correctly for keys that have been defined when provided the wrong type, but if I add a random key to the request body that has not been defined in the model then API Gateway just carries on processing the request and returns a 200 Success response.

How can I define, in the model, that random keys are not allowed?

**Model**

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "bool" : {
      "type" : "boolean"
    },
    "string" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "int" : {
      "type" : "integer",
      "format" : "int32"
    }
  }
}
```

**Request Body**
API GW Correctly Gives 200 Response

```
{
    "bool": true,
    "string": "foo",
    "int": 123
}
```

**Invalid Request Body**
API GW Correctly Gives 400 Response

```
{
    "bool": "foo",
    "string": 123,
    "int": false
}
```

**Invalid Request Body**
API GW Incorrectly Gives 200 Response

```
{
    "bool": true,
    "string": "foo",
    "int": 123,
    "bar":""
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing in the JSON schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to add the following to the model

```
"additionalProperties":false
```

**Model**

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "additionalProperties":false,
  "properties" : {
    "bool" : {
      "type" : "boolean"
    },
    "string" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "int" : {
      "type" : "integer",
      "format" : "int32"
    }
  }
}
```

from this issue
[Only allow properties that are declared in JSON schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530762/only-allow-properties-that-are-declared-in-json-schema/17531296)