# JSON schema validation, If there are additional keys they have to be of a specified name and type

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm a beginner to json (I do not have a history with JS) and only recently I've met with the need for json schema and it's validation. The problem could be described as:
I have 5 keys (properties) in my json; A, B, C, D, E, of which **A, B and C are required**, but **D and E are not**, specifically, every combination of D, E and their abscence is valid. However, **there cannot be any additional keys other than D and E**. Here's a couple examples (Items in sets represent keys of the object):

```
{A, B, C, D, E}  # valid
{A, B, C, D}     # valid
{A, B, C, E}     # valid
{A, B, C}        # valid

{A, B, D, E}     # invalid (C key is missing)
{A, B, C, D, Z}  # invalid (Z is not an allowed additional key)
{A, B, C, Z}     # invalid
```

First, I've tried writing my own validation function, which worked, but in our project we already use `jsonschema.validate` in other places and my supervisor told me to try solving this problem with the aforementioned method.
Here's the schema that was closed to solving the problem;

```
my_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "maxProperties": 5,
    "required": [
        "A", "B", "C"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "A": {"type": ["boolean", "number"]},
        "B": {"type": "array"},
        "C": {"type": "number"},
        "D": {"type": "string"},
        "E": {"type": "string"}
    }
}
```

however a test case where the keys are:

```
{A, B, C, D, Z}
```

is passing as a valid schema whereas it should not.

Comment: does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531296/202168

Comment: @Anentropic Yes! I've searched far and wide for the solution before posting the question, but I probably wasn't wording it right so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `"maxProperties": 5` you could use `"additionalProperties": False`

Here in code:

```py
import json
from jsonschema import Draft7Validator

my_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": False,
    "required": [
        "A", "B", "C"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "A": {"type": ["boolean", "number"]},
        "B": {"type": "array"},
        "C": {"type": "number"},
        "D": {"type": "string"},
        "E": {"type": "string"}
    }
}

data = {
    "A": True,
    "B": [1, 2, 3],
    "C": 1,
    "D": "test",
    "E": "test"
}

validator = Draft7Validator(my_schema)
validator.validate(data)
```

The above will validate fine, while the below will fail:

```py
bad_data = {
    "A": True,
    "B": [1, 2, 3],
    "C": 1,
    "D": "test",
    "Z": "test"
}

validator.validate(bad_data)
```

It will give you this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/danielsc/git/bwinf/41/Junior2/test.ipynb Cell 70 in <cell line: 10>()
      1 bad_data = {
      2     "A": True,
      3     "B": [1, 2, 3],
   (...)
      6     "Z": "test"
      7 }
      9 validator = Draft7Validator(my_schema)
---> 10 validator.validate(bad_data)

File /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/hugging/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py:269, in create.<locals>.Validator.validate(self, *args, **kwargs)
    267 def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
    268     for error in self.iter_errors(*args, **kwargs):
--> 269         raise error

ValidationError: Additional properties are not allowed ('Z' was unexpected)

Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'properties': {'A': {'type': ['boolean', 'number']},
                    'B': {'type': 'array'},
                    'C': {'type': 'number'},
                    'D': {'type': 'string'},
                    'E': {'type': 'string'}},
     'required': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
     'type': 'object'}

On instance:
    {'A': True, 'B': [1, 2, 3], 'C': 1, 'D': 'test', 'Z': 'test'}
```

Comment: That's precisely it. What I didn't consider is that non-required properties are omitted by "additionalProperties"  when validating

Comment: Yes, `additionalProperties: False` just means: Nothing above what is listed in the `properties` section.